# Return all documents from elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, go

My question is specific to the "gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v2" package I am using.

I am trying to return all documents that match my query:

```
termQuery := elastic.NewTermQuery("item_id", item_id)
searchResult, err := es.client.Search().
    Index(index).
    Type(SegmentsType). // search segments type
    Query(termQuery).   // specify the query
    Sort("time", true). // sort by "user" field, ascending
    From(0).Size(9).
    Pretty(true). // pretty print request and response JSON
    Do()          // execute
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
    return timeline, err
}
```

The problem is I get an internal server error if I increase the size to something large.  If I eliminate the line that states:

```
From(0).Size(9).
```

then the default is used (10 documents).  How may I return all documents?

Comment: I use the same library and a very similar search with a string query without issues. Could you share more details about the error and also clarify what "something large" means?

Comment: If you want to retrieve more than 10000 documents (default limit), you need to implement scrolling. The library you're using provides [some examples](https://github.com/olivere/elastic/blob/release-branch.v5/scroll_test.go) of how to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a scroller to retrieve all results is just a bit different and in the interest of brevity I'm not including much error handling that you might need.

Basically you just need to slightly change your code from `Search` to `Scroller` and then loop with the `Scroller` calling `Do` and handling pages of results.

```
termQuery := elastic.NewTermQuery("item_id", item_id)
scroller := es.client.Scroller().
    Index(index).
    Type(SegmentsType). 
    Query(termQuery).   
    Sort("time", true). 
    Size(1)

docs := 0
for {
    res, err := scroller.Do(context.TODO())
    if err == io.EOF {
        // No remaining documents matching the search so break out of the 'forever' loop
        break
    }
    for _, hit := range res.Hits.Hits {
        // JSON parse or do whatever with each document retrieved from your index
        item := make(map[string]interface{})
        err := json.Unmarshal(*hit.Source, &item)
        docs++
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't find the `Scroller` func, has it been changed to something else? Or do I have to manually retrieve the `ScrollID` and keep looping and updating it.