# go-elasticsearch fetch all documents

Tags: go, elasticsearch, search

I am trying to use go-elasticsearch to fetch all data from ES.

```
"github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v8"
"github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v8/esapi"
```

So far I have written this code:

```
var r map[string]interface{}    
cfg := elasticsearch.Config{
    Addresses: []string{
        fmt.Sprint(viper.Get("ELASTICSEARCH_URL")),
    },
}

es, err := elasticsearch.NewClient(cfg)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error creating the client: %s", err)
}
res, err := es.Search(
    es.Search.WithContext(context.Background()),
    es.Search.WithIndex(index_name),
    es.Search.WithTrackTotalHits(true),
    es.Search.WithPretty(),
    es.Search.WithFrom(0),
    es.Search.WithSize(1000),
)

if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error getting response: %s", err)
}
defer res.Body.Close()

if res.IsError() {
    var e map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&e); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error parsing the response body: %s", err)
    } else {
        // Print the response status and error information.
        log.Printf("[%s] %s: %s",
            res.Status(),
            e["error"].(map[string]interface{})["type"],
            e["error"].(map[string]interface{})["reason"],
        )
    }
}

if err := json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&r); err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error parsing the response body: %s", err)
}
// Print the response status, number of results, and request duration.
log.Printf(
    "[%s] %d hits; took: %dms",
    res.Status(),
    int(r["hits"].(map[string]interface{})["total"].(map[string]interface{})["value"].(float64)),
    int(r["took"].(float64)),
)
fmt.Println("length", len(r["hits"].(map[string]interface{})["hits"].([]interface{})))
domain := fmt.Sprint(viper.Get("DOMAIN"))
for _, hit := range r["hits"].(map[string]interface{})["hits"].([]interface{}) {
    doc := hit.(map[string]interface{})
    source := doc["_source"]
}
```

I want to fetch all documents from this index, I won't know how many documents will be there in the index. How do I do that? The max limit, by default, to fetch data at a time, is set to 10000.

Comment: May i know the use case please , to guide better ?

Answer (score 2):

- You can do that by [Scrolling](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#scroll-search-results) search results.
- Prefer not to scroll unless needed, as scrolling operation is costly

Comment: I am unsure about how to implement scrolling in Go. I am new to this language.

Comment: i even don't know go .. Please check this if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426733/return-all-documents-from-elasticsearch-query

Don't forget to upvote/accept as answer if it help